# Why you should never buy a broom or wash blankets in May?

Tags: superstition, european-folklore, british

According to [Project Britain's folklore calendar](http://projectbritain.com/year/may.htm) buying a broom or washing blankets in May should be avoided:

> Never buy a broom in May or wash blankets.
>
> *Wash a blanket in May.*
> *Wash a dear one away.*

Why is that so? Where does this superstition come from?